# How can I use a $_POST variable as part of a file path on a different page - PHP

Tags: php, html, variables, post

I am fairly new to PHP.

I am having trouble with a File upload page I am building. Basically, in the file upload form I have a drop down box with a list of categories. The user browses and selects a file, and then selects a category before submitting the file.

The file is supposed to upload to a folder on the server set dynamically by the code (user_data/username/fileType/filename) but what I am actually getting is (user_data/username//filename)

I am passing the drop down list variable as $_POST but for some reason i can't get it to populate the file path. I'm sure its something simple but I am stuck. Here is my code

### fileupload.php

```
<html>
<?php
if (isset($_POST["file"])) {
            $selected = $_POST["fileType"];
        }

        //$selected = $_POST['fileType']
?>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br><br />
<label for="docType">File Type:</label>
<select name="File Type" id="fileType">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Select Upload File Type:</option>
<option value="Evac_Dgm"> Evacuation Diagram</option>
<option value="Evac_Man"> Evacuation Manual</option>
<option pvalue="Warden_List">Warden List</option>
<option value="Att_Record">Attendance Record</option>
</select>



<br /><br />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


</html>
```

==============

### upload_file.php

```
<?php
echo $_POST['fileType'];

$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "pdf");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    $session = $_SESSION['username'];
    //$selected = $_POST['fileType'];
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("user_data/" . $session . "/" . $_POST['fileType'] . "/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "user_data/" . $session . "/" . $_POST['fileType'] . "/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "user_data/" . $session . "/" . $_POST['fileType'] . "/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Any help you guys could give would be awesome.

Comment: You can't have spaces for named form elements `<select name="File Type" id="fileType">`

Comment: Fred -ii- thanks for your help. I appreciate your helped. This is all now working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the space from the name of your `<select>` field.

Change:

```
<select name="File Type" id="fileType">
```

To:

```
<select name="FileType" id="fileType">
```

Also, here are some more comments for your HTML code:

```
<!-- Did you mean <label for="fileType"> ? -->
<label for="docType">File Type:</label>

<select name="File Type" id="fileType">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Select Upload File Type:</option>
<option value="Evac_Dgm"> Evacuation Diagram</option>
<option value="Evac_Man"> Evacuation Manual</option>

<!-- You have a typo below, should be <option value="... (there's an extra 'p') -->
<option pvalue="Warden_List">Warden List</option>
<option value="Att_Record">Attendance Record</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Dude thanks so much for your help. I knew it would be something simple!! Just needed a fresh set of eyes on the code!